# Does Rails_Admin support JSON?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

Upon running the installer for 'rails_admin':

```
rails g rails_admin:install
```

I get the following error:

```
Unsupported field datatype: json (RuntimeError)
```

I'm working w/ a Rails 4 application that has a few different models. One of which has a JSON attribute (note: the model w/ the JSON attribute is not my existing 'user' model).

Is this simply a result of rails_admin not playing nicely w/ Rails 4? Or am I doing something incorrect on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! - support for json field types was added Feb. 2014:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/1757

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1715

Answer (score 1):

At this time it looks like there's a pull request that's in limbo. So for now, no.

For a workaround, you can try just skipping any models that use a json field.

edit your config/initializers/rails_admin.rb file, to look like this:

(let's say i have json fields in models called Authorization and Tweet)

```
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
  ... # could have some other stuff here
  # Exclude specific models (keep the others):
  config.excluded_models = ['Authorization', 'Tweet']
  ... # could have some other stuff here
end
```

then run or rerun

```
rails g rails_admin:install
```

it should succeed and then tell you to migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that rails_admin doesn't support postgres arrays, and now I'm getting the same error for the json field type, I'm gonna go with no it does not.